Phub fullscreenchange event problem, gives Failed to execute 'requestFullscreen' message
On Phub I am getting Failed to execute 'requestFullscreen', API can only be initiated by a user gesture error when waiting for "fullscreenchange" event. Somehow fullscreenchange event triggers the error message in console without firing my event. Does anoyone know why Phub does this?
I am now using setInterval and document.fullScreenElement to check for fullscreen change but I'd like to know what's going on there. I am developing a browser extension and Pr0nhub is one site that throws it off like this.
